# Adding UIButton to UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to add a UIButton to UITabBar in my iPad application with following code:

```
TabBarAppDelegate *delegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)delegate.window.rootViewController;

UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[tabbar.view addSubview:b];
```

`tabbar` is OK and referencing to a correct tabbar item (say, I can switch active tab with following code: `[tabbar setSelectedIndex:1];`).

This code is called by some other custom button. Though there are no errors in the log, the button doesn't show on the tabbar :(

What am I doing wrong and what is a right way to add UIButton to UITabBar? :) Here is an example:

http://gyazo.com/99fc0df0ed47dd6be91b558161cab4f9.png

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** OK, if I'll stick to UIToolbar option, then what is a right way to switch between views? Create an NSArray of ViewContollers and load corresponding ViewController's view to an active View?

Comment: Why do you want to add a button? Do you want to add a new tab?

Comment: No, I really need to add a custom UIButton. That's what my client wants... This button is not a TabBarItem, it's just a button inside tabbar: http://gyazo.com/99fc0df0ed47dd6be91b558161cab4f9.png

Comment: @WASD42: That looks to me like a `UIToolBar` not a `UITabBar`, and you can easily add buttons to the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a `UIButton` directly to a `UITabBarController`. From the [`UITabBarController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should never access the tab bar view of a tab bar controller
>   directly.

Further along, the documentation reads:

> Tab bar items are configured through their corresponding view
>   controller. To associate a tab bar item with a view controller, create
>   a new instance of the UITabBarItem class, configure it appropriately
>   for the view controller, and assign it to the view controller’s
>   tabBarItem property. If you do not provide a custom tab bar item for
>   your view controller, the view controller creates a default item
>   containing no image and the text from the view controller’s title
>   property.

Therefore your two options are:

1. Create a `UITabBarItem` ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarItem)) and add that.
2. Use a `UIToolBar` instead, but remember to add `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Comment: Well, I do really need a `UITabBar` with button. If it's not possible with standard element it seems I'll need to create my own implementation of it :/ That's not so fun...

Comment: You should **not** subclass `UITabBar`. Why do you need a button? You can set up the action for the button to be triggered whenever the tab is selected.

Comment: I need to open popup when user clicks on the button and that's not want I want - that's what my client want :/ You said that it possible to call an action when the tab item clicked... Can I somehow disable the native of the tabitem behaviour then (I mean switching views)?

Comment: @wasd42, yes, but if you do it's extremely unlikely that apple will approve the app. use a toolbar to achieve this, from what you describe, it has the functionality you're after

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP has decided to use a UIToolBar to solve this, I thought I would post a quick response suggesting another option for anyone reading this. Basically, you can do this, but what you have to do is subclass the UITabBarController, and create your UIButton(s) and add them in the subclass. Anyhow, here are a couple of links that provide details.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588752/add-a-uibutton-as-a-subview-to-a-uitabbar)
[and Here](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles over this old question: You probably want to have a look at the respective delegates of `UITabBar` and `UITabBarController` (`UITabBarDelegate` and `UITabBarControllerDelegate`).