# Add a UIButton as a subview to a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to implement a hideable UITabBar in my app. I've set up all the animations, and they work very well. I'm just having an issue getting my UIButton "pull-tab" to show the tab bar. It is not responding to the touch event UIControlEventTouchUpInside.
I add the pull-tab to the UITabBar in the UITabBarController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//Add pull
    pullButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarPull.png"];
    pullButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBar.frame.size.width - image.size.width, -image.size.height + 3, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [pullButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pullButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pullBarTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pullButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.tabBar addSubview:pullButton];
}
```

Here is what the tab bar looks like open and closed:

[image: TabBar not hidden]
[image: TabBar Hidden]

Edit: I've determined that the problem is because the button falls outside the UITabBar's frame. Looks like I'm going to have to put the button outside of the UITabBar... Animation nightmare.

Comment: Well, its POSSIBLE that you could subclass UITabBar, figure out how to get your subclass used in UITabBarController (subclass it), then in your UITabBar subclass create a larger frame, have the UITabbar use its normal frame, but now your subclass should get all the taps etc. If it were me, I'd first try to just do the UITabBar subclass in a demo project, only when that works try to get it to work with all the other machinery. Good luck!

Comment: @Brandon Mcq Hey I am looking to the same thing-- did you ever come up with a good solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon Mcq Just saw your github, taking a look at that thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still add the `UIButton` to the `UITabBarController`'s main view, not in the `UITabBar` though.... `[myUITabBarController.view addSubview:pullButton]`

Comment: This worked, thanks. I created a sample project and put it on github. [link](http://github.com/Marxon13/HideableTabBar)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the hiding part working within the UITabbar and from the answer i have seen here, one alternative would be to keep the UIButton within the UITabbar but also add the button  to the view when the UITabbar is hidden (so you will have two button that overlay). When the tabbar is displayed hide the button you have added to the view using the **hidden** property on the view.