# Adding a UIButton in UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit

Is it possible to add a UIButton in UITabbar? I want to add a button on the right of all the UITabs. Been trying to figure this out for hours. Thanks you.

Comment: Programmatically or on the storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard if possible. Either way is fine. In IB, I can't just drag and drop a UIButton in the UITabBar thought.

Comment: Wait, do you want a `UIButton`?  Or a `UITabBarItem`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588752/add-a-uibutton-as-a-subview-to-a-uitabbar?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot add a UIButton directly** to a **UITabBarController**. From the [UITabBarController Class Reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You should never access the tab bar view of a tab bar controller directly.

**Further along, the documentation says:**

> Tab bar items are configured through their corresponding view
>   controller. To associate a tab bar item with a view controller, create
>   a new instance of the UITabBarItem class, configure it appropriately
>   for the view controller, and assign it to the view controller’s
>   tabBarItem property. If you do not provide a custom tab bar item for
>   your view controller, the view controller creates a default item
>   containing no image and the text from the view controller’s title
>   property.

**Therefore your two options are:**

Create a UITabBarItem (documentation) and add that.

Use a UIToolBar instead, but remember to add UIBarButtonItems.